# Conditional Probability involving a mathematical sequence

Tags: probability, conditional

I have a sequence of elements:

$$
T_1 \hspace{1cm}  P(T1 = A) = .5 \, , \\
T_2 \hspace{1cm}  P(T2 = B) = .2\, , \\
T_3 \hspace{1cm}  P(T3 = C) = .3\, .
$$

Given the sequence $TT = (T_1 = A, T_2 = B, T_3 = C)$, the probability of
that specific sequence will be $.5 \cdot .2 \cdot .3 = .03$.

But what is the conditional probability of $P(T_2 | TT)$ ?

Since we know that $TT$ is  $(A, B, C)$, it seems that
the conditional probability $P(T_2 = B | TT) = 1$.

It that correct?

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

First, in general
$$
P(TT)=P(T_1=A, T_2=B, T_3=C)= \\ 
P(T_1=A) \cdot P(T_2=B) \cdot P(T_3=C) = .5 \cdot .2 \cdot .3
$$
only if $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ are three mutually independent variables. If they are not, the probability would be
$$
P(TT)=P(T_1=A, T_2=B, T_3=C)= \\
P(T_1=A |  T_2=B, T_3=C) \cdot P(T_2=B |T_3=C) \cdot P(T_3=C)
$$

Secondly, indeed $P(T_2=B|TT) = P(T_2=B| T_1=A, T_2=B, T_3=C) =1$, as the condition ensures that $T_2=B$, regardless of whether $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ are mutually independent variables or not.

We also have that $P(T_2=D|TT)=0$ for all $D \neq B$.